# fastboot flash = FAILED (remote: invalid bootloader image)

Tags: rom-flashing, nexus-5, bootloader, fastboot

After breaking CyanogenMod on my Nexus 5 I want to flash it with a factory image but all I get is:

```
fastboot flash bootloader bootloader-flounder-3.43.0.0114.img
sending 'bootloader' (2970 KB)...
OKAY [  0.270s]
writing 'bootloader'...
FAILED (remote: invalid bootloader image
)
finished. total time: 0.450s
```

The same happens when I do `fastboot flash boot boot.img` with `FAILED (remote: image is not a boot image)` etc.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks like you've got the wrong factory image. You're trying to flash the bootloader for flounder (which I believe is for the Nexus 9). You need to download a Nexus 5 factory image which should contain a bootloader called `bootloader-hammerhead-hhz12d.img` (or similar)

Comment: I now downloaded the `hammerhead-lrx22c-factory-0f9eda1b` instead of the `volantisg-lrx22c-factory-a9668749` and it worked flawlessly.